# Strange error in logcat on Nexus 5

Tags: android, logging, nexus-5

My nexus started logging this error recently.
It's annoying and I can't debug other apps because this error comes repetedly:

```
01-11 11:02:46.026  27880-28017/? E/LocalFingerprints﹕ cannot compute fingerprint for: content://media/external/images/media/177595
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
            at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:689)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1080)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:921)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:646)
            at hna.a(PG:160)
            at hlc.a(PG:143)
            at com.google.android.libraries.social.autobackup.FingerprintScannerIntentService.onHandleIntent(PG:77)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: did you try filtering logs for specific app in logcat?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk How can I define fingerprint? My tablet has no finger print scanner!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on an LG G6.